# How to force third party React components to follow styling rules?

Tags: reactjs

React does not support !important to override whatever was set in the node module I'm using (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snowfetti):

If you look at the build process for this module, the height and width are set by numbers so they don't scale correctly with window size. I just wanted to use this as a background for my landing page. However, I can't force this component to so much as stay within its container. It also overlays any text I put on the screen despite giving it a z-index.

I decided to rebuild my website in React so this is just the very basics right now:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Snowfetti from 'react-snowfetti';

import "./App.css"

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="landing_header">
                    <h1>Coding on a cold day</h1>
                    <p>I find that things are nice and cold here</p>
                </div>
                <div className="snowfetti">
                      <Snowfetti/>;  
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.landing_header {
  z-index: 10000;
  color: white;
}

.snowfetti {
  z-index: -10000;
   /* display: none;  */
  width:800px;
  height:600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

All in all, is there a simple, straightforward way of forcing this component to do what I want? Otherwise, I think I'll just use particlejs.

Comment: why wouldn't react support `!important`statements? Anyway, have you tried setting your css inline as per documentation? 
`<Snowfetti styles={ zIndex: -10000, width: '800px'..., ...} />`?

Comment: I understand what you're getting at but in my limited experience inline styling is not good practice and more often than not does not work as well as !important in forcing stylings onto third party components.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override their styles using something similar to the following pattern:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        const snowfettiStyles = {
          zIndex: '-10000',
          width: '800px',
          height: '600px',
          overflow: 'hidden'
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="landing_header">
                    <h1>Coding on a cold day</h1>
                    <p>I find that things are nice and cold here</p>
                </div>
                <div className="snowfetti">
                      <Snowfetti styles={snowfettiStyles} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: When I implement this it simply makes the component "Snowfetti" not appear period. Additionally, I don't think in line styling would overwrite what is written in the module. I'm not sure why it makes the component disappear entirely as there is no error logged in console.

Comment: I've never used "snowfetti", but according to their docs you need to pass the object to the styled tag in order to overwrite / customize their styles. Your only other option would be to use an !important flag in our CSS.